# Could'nt create genreated column?

Tags: mysql

```
-- creating a virtual column
  ALTER TABLE membership_registration
  ADD COLUMN buyer_name VARCHAR(150) GENERATED ALWAYS 
  AS (concat(buyer_last_name,', ',buyer_first_name)) 
  COMMENT 'virtual column of buyer name' AFTER buyer_name_old;
```

the above query runs fine at local host  but the same query is not executing at production  and my sql work bench.

Comment: MYSQL versions? 5.7 on supports generated columns..And you should try to keep dev in step with production to avoid this kind of thing.

Comment: Like @P.Salmon says you should use the same versions on dev and production.. Topicstarter a few possible workarounds could be to use a VIEW instead off a generated column or add the `CONCAT(..)` to the select when you need the data.